# whenever cause uninitialized constant error in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-5

After confirming the operation in the local environment, I deployed it in the production environment.
The first time I made a mistake in the code and got an `undefined method` error.
After fixing the code and deploying it again, the following error appeared.

When I searched, there were articles such as being not read if it was under lib, but I thought that it was not applicable because it was under models.
It would be appreciated if you could borrow someone's wisdom.

```
# log/cron.log
Running via Spring preloader in process 7298
Please specify a valid ruby command or the path of a script to run.
Run 'bin/rails runner -h' for help.

uninitialized constant Item
```

```sh
# crontab -l

# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /var/www/rails/myapp/config/schedule.rb at: 2019-06-10 16:14:42 +0000
0 2 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/rails/myapp && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Item.reload'\'' >> /var/www/rails/myapp/log/cron.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /var/www/rails/myapp/config/schedule.rb at: 2019-06-10 16:14:42 +0000
```

#### environment

ruby: 2.5.0
rails: 5.2.3
サーバー: Amazon Linux 2 AMI

#### code

```
config/schedule.rb
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/environment")

set :output, "#{Rails.root}/log/cron.log"
set :environment, :production

every 1.day, at: '02:00' do
  runner 'Item.reload'
end
```

```
# models/item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def self.reload
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you migrate your database in production?

Comment: Yes, I migrated

Comment: Welcome to SO, land! are you sure application loads properly?

Comment: Thank you, Nick. 
I have confirmed that this application can be accessed from the web.

Comment: I think this error appears because the model can not be read from cron, but I do not know why it is not read

Comment: check the project path using 'crontab -l' whether the path is set correctly.

Comment: I updated 'crontab -l' result, path is right.

Comment: Are you using spring on your production server? The first block of code (with the log output) mentions spring but it's not clear if that's from local development or production.

Comment: Sorry! This is production log. 
The other person told me that spring does not work in production.